# Are there any reasons to make all fields and variables final?

Tags: java, coding-style, final

In my current project I noticed that all class fields and variable inside methods are declared with final modifier whenever it's possible.

Just like here:

```
private final XMLStreamWriter _xmlStreamWriter;
private final Marshaller _marshaller;
private final OutputStream _documentStream;

private final OutputStream _stylesStream;
private final XMLStreamWriter _stylesStreamWriter;
private final StyleMerger _styleMerger;

public DocumentWriter(PhysicalPackage physicalPackage) throws IOException {
    final Package pkg = new Package(physicalPackage);

    final Part wordDocumentPart = pkg.createPart(
            "/word/document.xml",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml",
            "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument");

    // styles.xml
    final Pair<Part, String> wordStylesPart = wordDocumentPart.createRelatedPart(...);
    ...
}
```

Are there any reasons to do so?

p.s. As I know project is not supposed to be multithreaded (at least I've heard nothing about it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write final you are signalling both to the compiler and the human reader that this variable is set once and then not changed.

The compiler uses it to check that you don't accidentally reassign a variable. If you do this it will give a compile error.

The human reader can use it to understand the intention of the code more quickly.

Missing it out typically won't cause your code to fail, but if you want a field to not change it is a good idea to say that explicitly. Note also that sometimes the final is mandatory, for example when using local classes:

> In addition to accessing fields defined by the containing class, local classes can access any local variables, method parameters, or exception parameters that are in the scope of the local method definition and declared final.

On the other hand, there might be times when you do want to be able to reassign to a variable. Obviously in this case you should not declare it as final.

Comment: I've never before seen all variables to be marked final. That's why I'm curious. I don't think that developers wanted to say 'don't touch anything here'. It looks like a coding style.

Comment: If you are consistent in writing final then when there isn't a final it's a signal to the developers to watch out because this value might change. It would perhaps be better if the default were final instead of non-final, and that you had to specify non-final. But that's the way Java is and it's not going to change.

Answer (score 4):

In programming it is best to get a compiler error than a logic error. Compiler errors are found in seconds and are corrected very fast.

final keyword can help to convert logic errors into compiler errors without too much effort.

For example:

```
public int test(int num){
   num = 10;
   x = num*2
   return  x;
}
```

In the example above we could accidentally assign a new value to num variable so the return value will be wrong. With final keyword we prevent this kind of errors.

```
public int test(final int num){
       num = 10; //compiler error
       x = num*2
       return  x;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Immutable classes are inherently thread safe in which you can share safely across threads.  If you declared all fields of a class final (and the class itself is final) also assuming each field itself is immutable, that object would be safe to share across threads.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically JVM can optimize those better, but I don't know if it really does. *final* is used to indicate that you can assign a value to the variable only once.

Comment: I've heard that modern JVMs ignore final for optimization purposes, but it's still useful as a compile-time check.

Comment: @Stuart, what do you mean ignore?  The JVM was changed to account for a bug in final fields being intiailized.  A final field's initialization is very important to thread safe code.

Comment: I meant only that "final" has no effect on how the JVM optimizes compiled code.  I'm not certain about this.

Answer (score -1):

And practically the object is in 2 or even more classloaders like app server environment and therefore will get assigned more than once even final. Or load a declared final from a properties file later changed, happened here removing declared final to normal variables got more pragmatic.

Comment: Are you confusing `final` with `static`?